# Creating global roles in Azure ?

Tags: azure, azure-role-environment

As I understand when a role is created in azure are only available in the assignable scope they are defined with. When in a new subscription I would not be able to call the role or assign it.

If I were to create a new role in the current subscription with the same name, it would throw an error as the role already exists.

Is there a way around this ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't think you are correct.

"Custom roles are stored in an Azure AD tenant and can be shared across all subscriptions that use that tenant as the Azure AD directory for the subscription."

So you can assign that role across all subscriptions a tenant has. So effectively that means you don't have to recreate your role for every subscription your tenant has. And if subscriptions are assigned to different tenant you can create custom roles with the same name for each of those.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-custom-roles

Comment: If you look at the Assignable scope section. I understood it as saying , you can only assign it to scopes that have been defined there.     
"The AssignableScopes property of the custom role specifies the scopes (subscriptions, resource groups, or resources) within which the custom role is available for assignment".   

I have tested using roles in scopes other than the ones defined in assignable scopes to no avail.

Comment: So whats the problem, modify assignable scopes?

Comment: but in our practice we create a role for each subscription and call it role-SUBGUID and its assignable only in that subscription @nwarriorch

Comment: yeah , that looks like where we are headed as well. To modify assignable scope we would have to find out subscription its present in and then modify it.

Comment: well its not hard, when all the roles are called role-guid, role name is known, guids are know @nwarriorch